# How to insert in sequence order in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to migrate data from source to destination in sequence order, if the source data is not sequence order, I want to raise a error in destination table

Output:

```
SOURCE Table 
1
2
5
```

Destination

```
1
2
Error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could use `row_number()` to compare the "sequence" and `cast` to get get "error":

```
select case when field = rn then cast(field as varchar(max)) else 'error' end 
from (
    select field, row_number() over (order by field) rn
    from source
) t 
order by field
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a803/2)